# Rails 4 Mailer not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to send an email with Rails 4. The server raises no error but I cannot receive the mail in my mailbox... Here is my configuration :

*environnements/development.rb*

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@website.com'}
```

I'm sending the email like this :

user_mailer.rb

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions(user)
  mail :to => user.email, :subject => 'Instructions pour la reinitialisation de votre mot de passe'
end
```

*user.rb*

```
def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
  reset_perishable_token!
  UserMailer.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
end
```

Does anybody have an idea about why it is not sending the email?

Comment: have you checked a) the server logs, b) the mail logs, c) that you're sending it to the correct address? I would also much prefer using something like mailcatcher (http://mailcatcher.me) in development, instead of actually sending email.

Comment: There is nothing in the server logs.
Mail logs ? Where are they ?
And yes it's the correct address :/

Comment: So your server log doesn't mention sending the email at all? Are you actually calling this mailer method, and then calling `deliver` on the resulting mail object?

Comment: Have you written `deliver` after calling `deliver_password_reset_instructions`???

Comment: Can you use `sendmail` from the command line?

Comment: I'm calling it like this

@user.deliver_password_reset_instructions!

Comment: And I have written no deliver method

Comment: uh...... I assume `@user` is a User object, and you haven't shown us a definition for that method on a user object. You don't have to write a deliver method for mailers - they come with one. I think you should read over http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Urg forgot it, edit the post.

(that's the guide I read)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're generating an email, but then **not actually sending it**.

```
UserMailer.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self).deliver
```

Will actually deliver the email you are creating.

Read over http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer (section 2.1.4 - Calling the Mailer) for more details about how to use mailers in your app.

**Edit:** `deliver` has been deprecated in Rails 4.2, in favour of either `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`. For the same behaviour as `deliver` from previous versions of Rails, you should use `deliver_now` - `deliver_later` is meant to be used with ActiveJob and a background job processor.

Comment: Urg I feel bad. Thanks ><

Comment: @Aeradriel Don't feel bad, I just did the same thing. One curious factor though was initially I was sending to Delayed Job, which apparently still sent the email in dev. But when I removed the queuing, it was missing the deliver and stopped working.